# Add a UIButton to a UISearchBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

I would like to know how to add a UIButton to a UISearchBar like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJxYF.png]

Comment: I think that is a uitextfield not a uisearchbar.

Answer (score 1):

`UIButton` and `UISearchBar` are views. You can call `addSubview:` method to add button to bar:

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(100, 5, 30, 10);
[searchBar addSubview:btn];
```

Comment: Note that UISearchBar already has several buttons. There are: bookmarkButton, cancelButton, searchResultsButton. All they are disabled by default